# ListView Scroll whole layout/page

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

How can I make the ListView/Layout scroller to behave like modern layout like in android or windows 10. Currently the ListView scrollbar only applies to the ListView itself. I want the scroller to scroll the whole layout including the search bar in XAML.

I want also the ListView Items added to increment to the overall height of the ListView to achieve the effect.

Any available ways to do it with Native wpf xaml (No frameworks/dlls, just pure xaml/c#)

[image: Expectation vs Reality]

Code:

```
<local:BasePage x:Class="GeneralMerchandise.UI.Pages.UsersPage"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:a="clr-namespace:GeneralMerchandise.UI.AttachedProperties"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GeneralMerchandise.UI.Pages"
  xmlns:c="clr-namespace:GeneralMerchandise.UI.Converter"        
            xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:GeneralMerchandise.UI.ViewModel"
            mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
  Title="UsersPage">
<Page.DataContext>
    <viewmodel:UsersViewModel x:Name="VM"/>
</Page.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
                Grid.Row="0" 
                Background="{StaticResource DefaultBackground}">
        <TextBlock FontSize="{StaticResource FontSizeXLarge}"
               Text="Users" />
        <Border BorderThickness="0 0 0 1">
            <Grid>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="300">

                    <TextBox Style="{StaticResource FlatTextBox}"
                             Width="270"
                             Margin="8"
                             a:Hint.TextProperty="Search"
                             a:ClearableText.EnableClearTextProperty="True"
                             Text="{Binding Search, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <StackPanel.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="RadioButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource FlatToggle}">
                                <Setter Property="Padding"
                                        Value="15 10"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                                        Value="0 0 0 3"/>

                            </Style>
                        </StackPanel.Resources>
                        <RadioButton GroupName="Filter"
                                     Content="All"
                                     IsChecked="True" 
                                     Command="{Binding FilterActiveCommand}"
                                     CommandParameter="{x:Static viewmodel:UsersViewModel+FilterActiveProperty.None }"/>
                        <RadioButton GroupName="Filter" 
                                     Content="Active"
                                     Command="{Binding FilterActiveCommand}"
                                     CommandParameter="{x:Static viewmodel:UsersViewModel+FilterActiveProperty.Active }"/>
                        <RadioButton GroupName="Filter" 
                                     Content="Deactived"
                                     Command="{Binding FilterActiveCommand}"
                                     CommandParameter="{x:Static viewmodel:UsersViewModel+FilterActiveProperty.Deactivated }"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
                <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                Content="New"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Command="{Binding NewUserCommand}"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>

    <ListView Grid.Row="2" 
              Background="Transparent"
              ItemsSource="{Binding UsersDisplay}" 
              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              BorderThickness="0"
              Padding="20">
        <ListView.Resources>
            <c:UserDisplayDataFullnameConverter x:Key="FullnameConverter"/>
            <c:BoolToValueConverter TrueValue="Active" FalseValue="Deactivated" x:Key="BoolToStringConverter"/>
        </ListView.Resources>
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>


        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Style="{StaticResource PlainButton}"
                        Background="White"
                        DataContext="{Binding}"
                        Width="250"
                        Height="150"
                        Padding="5"
                        BorderThickness="2"
                        Margin="{StaticResource MarginSmall}"
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                        VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Button.ToolTip>
                        <ToolTip>
                            <TextBlock Text="NAME"/>
                        </ToolTip>
                    </Button.ToolTip>
                    <Grid >
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Ellipse Grid.Column="0" 
                                 Margin="5"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                 Height="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
                                 Fill="{StaticResource LightGrayBrush}"/>
                        <Ellipse Grid.Column="0"
                                 Margin="5"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                 x:Name="userPicturePopup"
                                 Height="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
                                 Width="Auto">
                            <Ellipse.Fill>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="{StaticResource UserIconMedium}"/>
                            </Ellipse.Fill>
                        </Ellipse>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1"
                                    Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource FullnameConverter}}" 
                                       TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"
                                       Margin="10 5"/>
                            <TextBlock Margin="10 5" 
                                       Text="{Binding Created, StringFormat=Created {0:d}}"/>
                            <TextBlock Margin="10 5" 
                                       Text="{Binding IsActive, Converter={StaticResource BoolToStringConverter}, StringFormat=Account Is {0}}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                            <Border BorderBrush="Transparent"
                                        BorderThickness="3"
                                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Have you tried to pack all elements which should be scrollable into a `ScrollViewer` and deactivate it in the `ListView`?

Comment: @LittleBit Oh yeah. Thanks !! It didn't came to my mind.
One thing about the scroll viewer is it made the Grid's width to infinity
So I had to bind it's width to the page's ActualWidth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your ListView, search bar, and whatever else you want to scroll inside of a ScrollViewer.